# Show that $T^{-1}(M)+T^{-1}(N) \leq T^{-1}(M+N)$ for $T:V \to W$ where $M,N \leq W$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces over the same field $\mathbb{F}$. Let $T:V \to W$ be a linear transformation. Denote the preimage of $Y \leq W$ under $T$ by $T^{-1}(Y)$. Suppose that $M,N \leq W$. Show that $T^{-1}(M)+T^{-1}(N) \leq T^{-1}(M+N)$.

What I have so far is the following:

Let $x \in T^{-1}(M)$ and $y \in T^{-1}(M)$. Then $x,y \in V$ and $T(x) \in M$ and $T(y) \in N$. Then $T(x) +T(y) \in M+N$, so that $x,y \in T^{-1}(M+N)$. So $T^{-1}(M)+T^{-1}(N) \subseteq T^{-1}(M+N)$.

Where I'm struggling is showing that $T^{-1}(M)+T^{-1}(N)$ is a subspace of $T^{-1}(M+N)$.

Do I fist need to show that $T^{-1}(M+N)$ is a subspace of $V$, then since $T^{-1}(M)+T^{-1}(N) \subseteq T^{-1}(M+N)$, then $T^{-1}(M)+T^{-1}(N) \leq T^{-1}(M+N)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T^{-1}(M)+T^{-1}(N)$ is the sum of two linear subspaces of $V$ and is therefore a linear subspace of $V$.

Now if $a + b \in T^{-1}(M)+T^{-1}(N)$ where $T(a) \in M$ and $T(b) \in N$, you have $T(a)+T(b) = T(a+b) \in T(M+N)$. Therefore $a+b \in T^{-1}(M+N)$ proving the desired inclusion.